# How can i link two cells together in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For eg:-
I have two cells linked A1 and C5
Cell A1 = hello
Cell C5 = hello

Case 1:
I edit cell A1 to Bonjour, this is the result:
Cell A1 = Bonjour
Cell C5 = Bonjour

Case 2:
But when i edit cell C5 to hello again, this is the result:
Cell A1 = Bonjour
Cell C5 = hello

The link breaks and A1 doesn't change

What can i do about it? I am new to excel.

Comment: A cell is either pure text/number or a formula. You can't link them together and keep changing a cell's content from a formula into a string and expect the link you made via formulae still to be there. You'd need to write some code in VBA.

Comment: Where can i find the code?

Comment: It can be hard to find code that does exactly what you are after. Most likely you can find some inspiration online, but you'd most probably need to adapt/write it yourself.